# Почему cron запускает код файла, которого нет?

Tags: cron, crontab

Вношу изменения в файл *.php*, который каждое утро в 9:00 запускается кроном, но в то же время будто где-то в кэше сохранилась старая версия файла. И вообще старая команда. Например я даже перевёл запуск файла на 8:55, и он нормально отрабатывает. Но старая версия этого файла всё равно пускается в 9:00. Причём в crontab (я вношу правки именно через этот файл) нету строки, где указан запуск этого скрипта в 9:00. Будто где-то ещё прописывается задания для планировщика, либо cron как-то закэшировал самого себя.

Comment: рестарт сервака

Comment: Обновите вопрос, и напишите хотябы вашу ос, и через какой инструмент, вы редактируете крон

Answer (score 0):

крон поддерживает свои "crontab" для каждого пользователя. Возможно задание заведено под другим пользователем.

```
crontab -u root
```

и т.д.